# unable to iterate through an object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object literal with various objects but I am unable to display the values in the webpage. I have tried 'for loop' method but it shows only one value. I want to display all question properties in questions object but with this code, I am able to display only one property.

```js
let questions = [{
    question: "Jinnah's first salary",
    choice1: 'Rs-1',
    choice2: 'Rs-1000',
    choice3: 'Rs-10000',
    choice4: 'Rs-100,000',
    correct: 'A'
  },
  {
    question: "First recognised Pakistan",
    choice1: 'USA',
    choice2: 'Iran',
    choice3: 'China',
    choice4: 'None',
    correct: 'B'
  },
  {
    question: "National bird",
    choice1: 'Bee',
    choice2: 'Parrot',
    choice3: 'Chokor',
    choice4: 'Peagon',
    correct: 'C'
  },
];


for (let i = 0; i <= questions.length; i++) {
  document.querySelector('.p').innerText = questions[i].question;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <div class="p"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're replacing the inner text of a single element with each value as fast as the browser can run your JS. If you want to display each question then you either need to create elements, or *append* each question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the `=` from the `for` loop because array is [zero based](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements) so you want to run from `0` down to the array length. In your case, the array length is 3 so the last item will be `questions[2]`. So the loop should run from `0` to `2`, not `3`.
2. Add `+` before the assignment of the `innerText` so the new text will be added to the already existing text (Read about [Addition assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment)).

```js
let questions = [{
    question: "Jinnah's first salary",
    choice1: 'Rs-1',
    choice2: 'Rs-1000',
    choice3: 'Rs-10000',
    choice4: 'Rs-100,000',
    correct: 'A'
  },
  {
    question: "First recognised Pakistan",
    choice1: 'USA',
    choice2: 'Iran',
    choice3: 'China',
    choice4: 'None',
    correct: 'B'
  },
  {
    question: "National bird",
    choice1: 'Bee',
    choice2: 'Parrot',
    choice3: 'Chokor',
    choice4: 'Peagon',
    correct: 'C'
  },
];


for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  document.querySelector('.p').innerText += questions[i].question;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <div class="p"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have one paragraph per question, you will have to generate each paragraph as HTML, for example as follows:

```
for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {  
   document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += "<p>"+questions[i].question+"</p>";
}
```